# @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) problem with @Id and sequence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am facing troubles with `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` and autogenerated table Ids.

Here below is my model:

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class MenuEntity {

    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    //...
}
```

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasting_menu")
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TastingMenuEntity extends MenuEntity {

    //...
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "simple_menu")
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SimpleMenuEntity extends MenuEntity {

    //...
}
```

In development process, I have defined a  `data.sql` scripts which inserts test data into my `H2` inmemory database. Those scripts will work fine **only if** I specify the `ID` value in the statement, in other case I get `NULL not allowed for column "ID"`. Thus, I have to set the `ID` in the insert statement (the issue does not appear in other entities with no inheritance strategy and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`).

A new problem comes: when the application tries to insert a `SimpleMenuEntity` on execution time an exception is thrown: `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.SIMPLE_MENU(ID)` because the `sequence` is still value `1` even it already has some test data.

I have some questions so far.

#### 1. Is my model right?

I have to use `@Entity` instead of `@MappedSuperclass` in my `abstract class` because it has `@ManyToOne` annotation.

`ID` property is common for all child tables, but I would like that each table has its own `id` sequence.

#### 2. How should I handle the autogenerated `ID` for `SQL` `INSERT` statements?

I definitive need the test data in my application for development porpouse.